# Python: manipulating large text files

Tags: python, file, text

I am trying to read a large txt file (1.6 GB) in order to store its content in dictionaries. I am facing a hard time reading the file and it takes a lot to be over with. Actually I don´t know the exact time required to run the whole code because I stopped after 10 min of waiting :(.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import fileinput
import time



def extractdata2():
    start_time = time.time()
    accel_data = { 'timestamp': [], 'sensor': [], 'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': [] }
    accel_uncalib_data = { 'timestamp': [], 'sensor': [], 'x_uncalib': [], 'y_uncalib': [], 'z_uncalib': [], 'x_bias': [], 'y_bias': [], 'z_bias': [] }
    gyro_data = { 'timestamp': [], 'sensor': [], 'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []}
    gyro_uncalib_data = { 'timestamp': [], 'sensor': [], 'x_uncalib': [], 'y_uncalib': [], 
'z_uncalib': [], 'x_drift': [], 'y_drift': [], 'z_drift': []}
    magnet_data = { 'timestamp': [], 'sensor': [], 'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': [] }
    magnet_uncalib_data = { 'timestamp': [], 'sensor': [], 'x_uncalib': [], 'y_uncalib': [], 'z_uncalib': [], 'x_bias': [], 'y_bias': [], 'z_bias': []}

    with open("accelerometer.txt") as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            line = line.split(',')
            if "TYPE_ACCELEROMETER" in line:
                    #IMU_data["accel_data"] = line  # the line must be split in 4 camps

                accel_data["timestamp"].append(line[ 0 ] )
                accel_data["sensor"].append( line[ 1 ] )
                accel_data["x"].append( line[ 2 ] )
                accel_data["y"].append( line[ 3 ] )
                accel_data["z"].append( line[ 4 ] )
                #print(accel_data)
            elif "TYPE_ACCELEROMETER_UNCALIBRATED" in line:
                accel_uncalib_data["timestamp"].append( line[ 0 ] )
                accel_uncalib_data["sensor"].append( line[ 1 ] )
                accel_uncalib_data["x_uncalib"].append( line[ 2 ] )
                accel_uncalib_data["y_uncalib"].append( line[ 3 ] )
                accel_uncalib_data["z_uncalib"].append( line[ 4 ] )
                accel_uncalib_data["x_bias"].append( line[ 5 ] )
                accel_uncalib_data["y_bias"].append( line[ 6 ] )
                accel_uncalib_data["z_bias"].append( line[ 7 ] )
                #print(accel_uncalib_data)
            elif "TYPE_GYROSCOPE" in line:
                gyro_data["timestamp"].append( line[ 0 ] )
                gyro_data["sensor"].append( line[ 1 ] )
                gyro_data["x"].append( line[ 2 ] )
                gyro_data["y"].append( line[ 3 ] )
                gyro_data["z"].append( line[ 4 ] )
                #print(gyro_data)
            elif "TYPE_GYROSCOPE_UNCALIBRATED" in line:
                gyro_uncalib_data["timestamp"].append( line[ 0 ] )
                gyro_uncalib_data["sensor"].append( line[ 1 ] )
                gyro_uncalib_data["x_uncalib"].append( line[ 2 ] )
                gyro_uncalib_data["y_uncalib"].append( line[ 3 ] )
                gyro_uncalib_data["z_uncalib"].append( line[ 4 ] )
                gyro_uncalib_data["x_drift"].append( line[ 5 ] )
                gyro_uncalib_data["y_drift"].append( line[ 6 ] )
                gyro_uncalib_data["z_drift"].append( line[ 7 ] )
                #print(gyro_uncalib_data)
            elif "TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD" in line:
                magnet_data["timestamp"].append( line[ 0 ] )
                magnet_data["sensor"].append( line[ 1 ] )
                magnet_data["x"].append( line[ 2 ] )
                magnet_data["y"].append( line[ 3 ] )
                magnet_data["z"].append( line[ 4 ] )
                #print(magnet_data)
            elif "TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED" in line:        
                magnet_uncalib_data["timestamp"].append( line[ 0 ] )
                magnet_uncalib_data["sensor"].append( line[ 1 ] )
                magnet_uncalib_data["x_uncalib"].append( line[ 2 ] )
                magnet_uncalib_data["y_uncalib"].append( line[ 3 ] )
                magnet_uncalib_data["z_uncalib"].append( line[ 4 ] )
                magnet_uncalib_data["x_bias"].append( line[ 5 ] )
                magnet_uncalib_data["y_bias"].append( line[ 6 ] )
                magnet_uncalib_data["z_bias"].append( line[ 7 ] )
                #print(magnet_uncalib_data)

    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    return accel_data, accel_uncalib_data, gyro_data, gyro_uncalib_data, magnet_data, magnet_uncalib_data
```

How can I speed up my routine? I have tried many of the types mentioned on stackoverflow in similar cases but it didn´t work.

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This may be better served at [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But I can't help but wonder if pyspark would better process such a large file for you.

Comment: your code might have broke due to memory issue, in that case try to take a chunk of the data at a time to process. Like using any sampling techniques

Comment: I'm wondering if pandas would be a better option for you.

Comment: @mauve almost certainly [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is the solution; I agree with you.

Comment: You should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944183/python-fastest-way-to-read-a-large-text-file-several-gb

Comment: @JoseRaulBarreras already tried the solutions from second post you listed here and it didn´t work. I will check the other one.

Comment: @mauve used pandas and it read the file in 30 seconds. I tried this:     'data = pd.read_csv('accelerometer.txt', sep=',', header = None)'
    'data.columns = [ "timestamps", "type", "x", "y", "z" ]'

Comment: That sounds like a time improvement to me! :)

Answer (score 0):

As Amey Yadav has already suggested reading the text file in chunks is a rather efficient solution. In order to do that I can think of two solutions.

First off, I would suggest writing a generator that process the text in chunks. You can then process each chunk any way you want.

Secondly a rather handy python library that helps with large corpora is [Gensim](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim). Going through the tutorials you'll find that it's pretty easy to use it in order to load documents into its topic modelling software, in a way that doesn’t require you to load the whole file into memory thus taking you vastly less time to process your data.