# Python: Reading matrices from file as float

Tags: python, file, matrix, python-itertools

I have a very large file (~20 GB) from which I want to read specific lines which represent a matrix. The data file for three 2 x 2 matrices looks like:

```
2 3
1 3
2 2
1 2
3 2
3 4
```

Currently I am using the following approach (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944183/python-fastest-way-to-read-a-large-text-file-several-gb)) where I get a list of strings.

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 2 # matrix size
t = 3 # number of matrices
file = open("data")
t = 0;
with file as f:
    while t < 3:
        t=t+1
        next_n_lines = list(islice(f, n))
        print(next_n_lines)
        plt.matshow(next_n_lines)
        plt.show()
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        # process next_n_lines
```

But how do I get floats instead of a list of strings? I don't see it, but it can't be so hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, itertools

n = 2
num_m = 3
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    for i in range(num_m):
        try:
            items = [list(map(float, i.split())) for i in itertools.islice(f, n)]
        except:
            raise
        else:
            plt.matshow(items)
            plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just `.split` the lines and map the `float` function onto the results, using list-comprehensions here, but whatever you want:

```
In [29]: from itertools import *
    ...: n = 2 # matrix size
    ...: t = 3 # number of matrices
    ...: with open('data') as f:
    ...:     for _ in range(t):
    ...:         s = islice(f, n)
    ...:         M = [[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in s]
    ...:         print(M)
    ...:
[[2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 3.0]]
[[2.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0]]
[[3.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]
```

Also note, it is a lot cleaner to use a for-loop rather than a while-loop.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy's `fromfile`can be useful here:

```
import numpy as np

n = 2 # matrix size
t = 3 # number of matrices

with open('data') as fobj:
    for _ in range(t):
        try:
            numbers = np.fromfile(fobj, count=n * n, sep=' ').reshape(n, n)
            plt.matshow(numbers)
            plt.show()
        except ValueError:
            break
```

Yields the desired output:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to specify the number of matrices in your code?

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.